# Does @synchronize protect Objects that are pointed to by other Objects?

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, cocoa-touch, synchronization

For example let's say we have objectA, which points to ObjectB, which points to objectC.

We then do

```
@synchronized(objectA) {
    [self doSomeStuff];
}
```

What is protected here from other threads? Just objectA, or objectB and objectC and anything that any object references all the way down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@synchronized(obj) {...}` merely means that whatever is in the `{...}` will not be executed concurrently with any other `@synchronized(obj)`'s `{...}`.

I.e. given:

thread 1:

```
@synchronized(objectA) {
    [self doSomeStuff];
}
```

thread 2:

```
@synchronized(objectA) {
    [self doSomeStuff];
}
```

thread 3:

```
[self doSomeStuff];
```

One of thread 1 or thread 2 will block while the other executes `doSomeStuff`, but thread 3 will merrily invoke `doSomeStuff` concurrently.

And, more directly to your question, that implies that, no, there is absolutely zero concurrency protection for anything that `doSomeStuff` might do internally.

If you want your objects to be "thread safe", they need to be designed from top to bottom with concurrency in mind (and that does not generally mean with tons of locks or synchronization primitives everywhere).

Answer (score 1):

`@synchronized(objectA)` creates critical section. In your example it guarantees, that `[self doSomeStuff]` will not be executed simultaneously by different threads.

`objectA` is used just to identify which implicitly created recursive lock will be used. Critical sections, created by `@synchronized` directive with same object as argument will not be executed simultaneously.

From Apple documentation:

> The @synchronized directive is a convenient way to create mutex locks
>   on the fly in Objective-C code. The @synchronized directive does what
>   any other mutex lock would do—it prevents different threads from
>   acquiring the same lock at the same time. In this case, however, you
>   do not have to create the mutex or lock object directly. Instead, you
>   simply use any Objective-C object as a lock token
>
> The object passed to the @synchronized directive is a unique
>   identifier used to distinguish the protected block. If you execute the
>   preceding method in two different threads, passing a different object
>   for the anObj parameter on each thread, each would take its lock and
>   continue processing without being blocked by the other. If you pass
>   the same object in both cases, however, one of the threads would
>   acquire the lock first and the other would block until the first
>   thread completed the critical section.